# Most useful Naxsi rules to maintain

Tags: nginx

After many searching on Google without finding anything useful, I would like to know what are the most useful rules of Naxsi to keep (even modified)
 and which I can safely ignore.

Below, my current configuration.

```
##################################
## INTERNAL RULES IDS:1-999     ##
##################################
#@MainRule "msg:weird request, unable to parse" id:1;
#@MainRule "msg:request too big, stored on disk and not parsed" id:2;
#@MainRule "msg:invalid hex encoding, null bytes" id:10;
#@MainRule "msg:unknown content-type" id:11;
#@MainRule "msg:invalid formatted url" id:12;
#@MainRule "msg:invalid POST format" id:13;
#@MainRule "msg:invalid POST boundary" id:14;
#@MainRule "msg:invalid JSON" id:15;
#@MainRule "msg:empty POST" id:16;
#@MainRule "msg:libinjection_sql" id:17;
#@MainRule "msg:libinjection_xss" id:18;
##################################
## SQL Injections IDs:1000-1099 ##
##################################
MainRule "rx:select|union|update|delete|insert|table|from|ascii|hex|unhex|drop" "msg:sql keywords" "mz:BODY|URL|ARGS|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$SQL:4" id:1000;
MainRule "str:\"" "msg:double quote" "mz:BODY|URL|ARGS|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$SQL:8,$XSS:8" id:1001;
MainRule "str:0x" "msg:0x, possible hex encoding" "mz:BODY|URL|ARGS|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$SQL:2" id:1002;
## Hardcore rules
MainRule "str:/*" "msg:mysql comment (/*)"  "mz:BODY|URL|ARGS|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$SQL:8" id:1003;
MainRule "str:*/" "msg:mysql comment (*/)" "mz:BODY|URL|ARGS|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$SQL:8" id:1004;
MainRule "str:|" "msg:mysql keyword (|)"  "mz:BODY|URL|ARGS|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$SQL:8" id:1005;
MainRule "str:&&" "msg:mysql keyword (&&)" "mz:BODY|URL|ARGS|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$SQL:8" id:1006;
## end of hardcore rules
MainRule "str:--" "msg:mysql comment (--)" "mz:BODY|URL|ARGS|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$SQL:4" id:1007;
MainRule "str:;" "msg:semicolon" "mz:BODY|URL|ARGS" "s:$SQL:4,$XSS:8" id:1008;
MainRule "str:=" "msg:equal sign in var, probable sql/xss" "mz:ARGS|BODY" "s:$SQL:2" id:1009;
MainRule "str:(" "msg:open parenthesis, probable sql/xss" "mz:ARGS|URL|BODY|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$SQL:4,$XSS:8" id:1010;
MainRule "str:)" "msg:close parenthesis, probable sql/xss" "mz:ARGS|URL|BODY|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$SQL:4,$XSS:8" id:1011;
MainRule "str:'" "msg:simple quote" "mz:ARGS|BODY|URL|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$SQL:4,$XSS:8" id:1013;
MainRule "str:," "msg:comma" "mz:BODY|URL|ARGS|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$SQL:4" id:1015;
MainRule "str:#" "msg:mysql comment (#)" "mz:BODY|URL|ARGS|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$SQL:4" id:1016;
MainRule "str:@@" "msg:double arobase (@@)" "mz:BODY|URL|ARGS|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$SQL:4" id:1017;

###############################
## OBVIOUS RFI IDs:1100-1199 ##
###############################
MainRule "str:http://" "msg:http:// scheme" "mz:ARGS|BODY|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$RFI:8" id:1100;
MainRule "str:https://" "msg:https:// scheme" "mz:ARGS|BODY|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$RFI:8" id:1101;
MainRule "str:ftp://" "msg:ftp:// scheme" "mz:ARGS|BODY|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$RFI:8" id:1102;
MainRule "str:php://" "msg:php:// scheme" "mz:ARGS|BODY|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$RFI:8" id:1103;
MainRule "str:sftp://" "msg:sftp:// scheme" "mz:ARGS|BODY|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$RFI:8" id:1104;
MainRule "str:zlib://" "msg:zlib:// scheme" "mz:ARGS|BODY|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$RFI:8" id:1105;
MainRule "str:data://" "msg:data:// scheme" "mz:ARGS|BODY|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$RFI:8" id:1106;
MainRule "str:glob://" "msg:glob:// scheme" "mz:ARGS|BODY|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$RFI:8" id:1107;
MainRule "str:phar://" "msg:phar:// scheme" "mz:ARGS|BODY|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$RFI:8" id:1108;
MainRule "str:file://" "msg:file:// scheme" "mz:ARGS|BODY|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$RFI:8" id:1109;
MainRule "str:gopher://" "msg:gopher:// scheme" "mz:ARGS|BODY|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$RFI:8" id:1110;

#######################################
## Directory traversal IDs:1200-1299 ##
#######################################                                          
MainRule "str:.." "msg:double dot" "mz:ARGS|URL|BODY|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$TRAVERSAL:4" id:1200;
MainRule "str:/etc/passwd" "msg:obvious probe" "mz:ARGS|URL|BODY|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$TRAVERSAL:4" id:1202;
MainRule "str:c:\\" "msg:obvious windows path" "mz:ARGS|URL|BODY|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$TRAVERSAL:4" id:1203;
MainRule "str:cmd.exe" "msg:obvious probe" "mz:ARGS|URL|BODY|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$TRAVERSAL:4" id:1204;
MainRule "str:\\" "msg:backslash" "mz:ARGS|URL|BODY|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$TRAVERSAL:4" id:1205;
#MainRule "str:/" "msg:slash in args" "mz:ARGS|BODY|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$TRAVERSAL:2" id:1206;

########################################
## Cross Site Scripting IDs:1300-1399 ##
########################################
#MainRule "str:<" "msg:html open tag" "mz:ARGS|URL|BODY|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$XSS:8" id:1302;
MainRule "str:<" "msg:html open tag" "mz:ARGS|URL|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$XSS:8" id:1302;
#MainRule "str:>" "msg:html close tag" "mz:ARGS|URL|BODY|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$XSS:8" id:1303;
MainRule "str:>" "msg:html close tag" "mz:ARGS|URL|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$XSS:8" id:1303;
MainRule "str:[" "msg:open square backet ([), possible js" "mz:BODY|URL|ARGS|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$XSS:4" id:1310;
MainRule "str:]" "msg:close square bracket (]), possible js" "mz:BODY|URL|ARGS|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$XSS:4" id:1311;
MainRule "str:~" "msg:tilde (~) character" "mz:BODY|URL|ARGS|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$XSS:4" id:1312;
MainRule "str:`"  "msg:grave accent (`)" "mz:ARGS|URL|BODY|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$XSS:8" id:1314;
MainRule "rx:%[2|3]."  "msg:double encoding" "mz:ARGS|URL|BODY|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$XSS:8" id:1315;

####################################
## Evading tricks IDs: 1400-1500 ##
####################################
MainRule "str:&#" "msg:utf7/8 encoding" "mz:ARGS|BODY|URL|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$EVADE:4" id:1400;
MainRule "str:%U" "msg:M$ encoding" "mz:ARGS|BODY|URL|$HEADERS_VAR:Cookie" "s:$EVADE:4" id:1401;

#############################
## File uploads: 1500-1600 ##
#############################
MainRule "rx:\.ph|\.asp|\.ht" "msg:asp/php file upload" "mz:FILE_EXT" "s:$UPLOAD:8" id:1500;
```

Thanks for any help,
Lorenzo.